# How i can create Android Sample Project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any easy way to create(import) Android Sample Project (in eclipse terminology) in Android Studio?
I mean something like eclipse `New Project->Android Sample Project` dialog

Comment: No. I only want to know is there any mechanism in AndStudio simmilar to eclipse's "new android sample project dialog"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android Studio 1.0.2

`File -> Import Sample...`

Then, if you are looking for Support Samples, these live under

```
/sdk/extras/android/support/samples/
```

You'll need to go to `File -> Import Project...`

Some of them still have Eclipse project structure, but AS will take care of that.

Comment: And you should know that sometimes you will miss the "Import Project"  menu ,then you can goto File==>Settings==>Appearance&Behavior ===>Menus android Toolbars===>Main menu ===>File ===>Add After ==>Main Menu ===>File==>Import Sample==>Ok, then ,the "Import Project" menu can show again

Answer (score 7):

Have you installed the samples for the SDK from your Android SDK Manager?  [Instructions for doing so can be found here](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html).

After those are installed, you can use the menu `File->Import Project...`

[image: installing SDK samples]

Comment: Yes, all samples are already downloaded in to \android-sdk\samples\. As you can notice, this folder contains only sources, no platform or ide depending files are there. Eclipse uses simple 2 step dialog to create new sample project in the workspace. Yes, i can use Import Project->From Existing sources->locate folder->check needed folders->review libraris found->review suggested module structure->select project sdk.

Comment: But this solution looks more complicated in comparison with eclipse.

Comment: @JohnnyDoe Yes its little complicated coz its an initial V0.1.